# Issues with a custom tab view combined with ScrollView

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, custom-view

The look of my tab view is great. Everything in fact looks good. But with the current code. The ScrollView ends behind the tab bar instead of above. I'm guessing it has to do with it being a ZStack (it - meaning the content).

I tried adding padding on each view inside the switch (padding bottom same height as tab bar but not working).

The two results I've gotten is either it won't scroll enough to see all content but tab bar looks good.

OR

Scrolling works great but the tab bar has some overlaying issues visually with showing whitespace.
I just don't know how to move around the code any more to get a better result. :(

```
//Landing-page..

        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .bottom)) {
            switch tabController.selectedIndex {
                case 0:
                    HomeView()
                        .padding(.bottom, 50)
                case 1:
                    Text("Test..")
                case 2:
                    Text("Test...")
                case 3:
                    Text("Test....")
                default:
                    VStack {
                        Text("Default View")
                    }
                }
                
                CustomTabView()
            }
        }
        .background(Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
```

```
// TabView..

        HStack {
            // tabControllers.icons.count = 4 tabs at the moment
            ForEach(0..<tabController.icons.count, id: \.self) { tab in
                Button(action: {
                    // animation when changing tab comes here eventually
                    tabController.selectedIndex = tab
                }, label: {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: tabController.icons[tab])
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .font(.system(
                                    size: 22,
                                    weight: tabController.selectedIndex == tab ? .semibold : .regular,
                                    design: .default))
                            .foregroundColor(tabController.selectedIndex == tab ? Color.themeAccent : Color.themeAccent.opacity(0.3))
                            .background(tabController.selectedIndex == tab ? Color.primaryPurple : nil)
                            .cornerRadius(tabController.selectedIndex == tab ? 30 : 0)
                        Spacer()
                })
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.blue)
        .clipShape(CShape())
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 20, x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
```

The ScrollView starts at the top in the HomeView.

[Tab view showing correctly, but not scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wQas.png)

[ScrollView showing correctly, but not tab view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8TAV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get rid of the `ZStack`, put the switch/case in the `VStack` and the `CustomTabView()` below that. The `ScrollView` will push the `CustomTabView` to the bottom and not overlap it. If not all of the views in the switch are `ScrollView`s, then you can add a `Spacer()` above the `CustomTabView`, which will push the views apart to the top and bottom.